# Inserting data to the specific node in XML file with PHP DOM

Tags: php, xml, dom, rss

I am trying to insert data into my RSS xml file using PHP DOM. 
These are the codes involved.

index.php

```
<html>
<head><title>test</title></head>
</head>

<form name="input" action="insert.php" method="post">
    insert item:
    <input type="text" name="item"/>
    <input type="submit" value="send"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

insert.php

```
<?php
header('Location:index.php');
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load('sample.xml');

$newAct = $_POST['activity'];

$root = $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0);

$newElement = $xmldoc->createElement('item');
$root->appendChild($newElement);
$newText = $xmldoc->createTextNode($newAct);
$newElement->appendChild($newText);

$xmldoc->save('sample.xml');
?>
```

sample.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">

<channel>
  <title>Bagnista Home Page</title>
  <link>example.com</link>
  <description>Bagnista Home Page</description>
  <atom:link href="example.xml" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml"/>
  <item>
    <title>Kelly 28 in Fuschia Pink</title>
    <link>example.com</link>
    <language>en</language>
    <pubDate>Wed, 04 Dec 2013 00:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
    <description>For rent. Price $10000</description>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">example.com</guid>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Birkin 30 in RougeVif GHW</title>
    <link>example.com</link>
    <language>en</language>
    <pubDate>Wed, 04 Dec 2013 00:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
    <description>For rent. Price $13000</description>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">example.com</guid>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Birkin 30, gold hardware</title>
    <link>example.com</link>
    <language>en</language>
    <pubDate>Wed, 04 Dec 2013 00:00:0 GMT</pubDate>
    <description>For sale. Price $14000</description>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">example.com</guid>
  </item>
</channel>

</rss>
```

Since I am using appendChild, the item tag will be below the last /item tag.
How can I insert the item tag before the first item tag?
I've tried insertBefore() but it failed for me.

Comment: Why not using a RSS lib around the web?

Comment: Different approach: insert the node wherever it inserts, but read from the XML sorting by `<pubDate>`.